# Counter cache and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

Is there any way to force will_paginate plugin to use counter_cache instead of using 
`SELECT count(*)` query? I've heard that Model.count is using by default counter caches. So will_paginate must use size method. How I can change the way it gathers amount of objects to be paginated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming two models, `Author` and `Comment`, where `Author` `has_many` `Comment`s using counter cache, you should be able to pass an option `:total_entries` to the `paginate`-method like this:

```
author = Author.first
posts  = author.posts.paginate :total_entries => author.posts_count
```

See more here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb#L128